# How to pass params to a HTTP request (teststep) in a SOAP UI Test case using groovy and run it

Tags: groovy, parameters, httprequest, soapui

I am writing a groovy script to execute/automate my test suite. In one test case i have a HTTPRequest where i have a request URL, parameters( username and password) and method( GET) to get a token-id and then i would pass that token id to my next step( a SOAP request)to get the data.

I am stuck at a point where i need to pass the params(username and password), request URL and method(GET) using groovy.
I have a test step created manaully under a test case, i just need to pass the params

as i search online i got to know how to pass headers,url  to a SOAP request which is like below

```
def headers = new StringToStringMap()
testRunner = new com.eviware............WsdlTestCaseRunner(myTestCase,null);
testStepContext = new com.eviware.soapui........WsdlTestRunContext(testsetp);
headers.put("apikey", "abcd")
teststep.getTestRequest().setRequestHeaders(headers)
teststep.getHttpRequest().setEndpoint(encpointurl);
testsetp.run(testRunner ,testStepContext )
```

but i looking to know how to pass params to a http request(test step) and run it.

Answer (score 1):

- Add a Properties teststep to your testcase. Just let it keep the default "Properties" name.
- Add the properties to the Properties teststep, that you need to transfer
- Inside your groovy teststep, you may set the properties using something like:

  def properties = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties");
  properties.setPropertyValue("name", "value");
- Add the parameters directly in your request using variables in the format ${Properties#name} and replace "name" with the actual parameter name. This can be done both in the request body and in the URL if you should wish to do so.

Comment: perfect, that works.

`testRunner.testCase.testSteps["TokenStep"].setPropertyValue( "username", "myusername" )`

Answer (score 1):

It can be done completely in groovy by using groovy.json.JsonBuilder Class.

```
def  body = new StringToStringMap()
def jsonbildr = new JsonBuilder()
 body.put("username","Hackme")
 body.put("password","LockUout")
def root  = jsonbildr body   
jsonbildr = jsonbildr.toPrettyString()
log.info(jsonbildr)
testStep.setPropertyValue("Request", jsonbildr)
```

**Output :**

```
  {
        "password": "LockUout",
        "username": "Hackme"
    }
```